# Не работает phpmyadmin на локальном сервере

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, localhost

Доброго времени суток!
На локальном сервере по пути localhost/phpmyadmin не работает сам PHPMyadmin.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Папка с phpmyadmin находится в /var/www/html/phpmyadmin.
Вот скрин прав на эту папку : 
https://snag.gy/Vvpuxj.jpg
Вот лог ошибки:

```
[Tue Nov 07 12:54:16.297911 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 16508] [client ::1:47590] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне нужно сделать чтобы нормально я смог работать с phpmyadmin?

Comment: Я б начал с того, что проверил если создать пустую папку например /var/www/html/phpmyadm будет ее открывать http://localhost/phpmyadm если открывает значат проблема с правами доступа к файлам, иначе настройки апача

Comment: alias/синоним этого короткого пути прописан в конфиге?

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов создал, к этой папке тоже 403 выдает.
Подскажите, где глянуть настройки апача ?

Comment: httpd.conf - настройки апача, проверьте там алиас, вот у меня написано `Alias /pma "D:/server/localhost/www/phpmyadmin"` в секции `<IfModule alias_module>`

Comment: @Jean-Claude подскажите, плиз, где конкретно должен быть прописан этот алиас ?

Comment: @Jean-Claude у меня нет таких файлов...
есть только такие https://snag.gy/ju2NMe.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл конфигурации Apache /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Ищете описание директории /var/www оно должно иметь такой вид

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Можно решить данный вопрос добавив описание своей директории, например такое

```
<Directory /var/www/html/phpmyadmin>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

После внесение изменений, нужно что б Апач перечитал конфиг sudo service apache2 reload

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло никак....Та же ошибка..

Comment: Можно попробовать еще переустановить права на все фалы phpmyadmin при помощи комманды sudo chmod 775 -R /var/www/html/phpmyadmin

Comment: тоже самое....уже и не знаю что делать

Comment: А адрес http://localhost открывается? Возможно проблема в /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Comment: открывается, вот содержимое этого файла 
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Comment: /var/log/apache2/error.log Что в этом тут пишет по поводу попыток Вашего доступа

Comment: [Tue Nov 07 16:17:31.877035 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 25303] [client ::1:36636] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/share

Comment: Ищите где в конфигурации Апача вы указали /var/share там проблема "зарыта"